# Guidance on wiring up my service layer with database access layer

Tags: scala, guice

I'm using the sse-guice library also in case this helps.

So I have a UserService class that looks something like:

```
class UserService {
   val datasource = DbHelper.getDataSource()
   val database = DBHelper.getDb(datasource)
   val userDao = new UserDao()

   def getUserById(userId: Int): User = {
      return userDao.getById(userId)
   }
}
```

So now in my MVC controller classes I want to inject my UserService.

How would I create a Guice Module to wire up these dependencies?

```
UserService => Singleton
datasource => singleton
database => singleton
actionDao => singleton
```

Also, Do I have to refactor my UserService and use a trait or abstract class?

Should I be creating a seperate module per XXXService or I should just create a single module like ServicesModule?

So something like:

```
class ServicesModule extends ScalaModule {
  def configure() {
     bind[UserService].to[UserServiceImpl]
  }
}
```

But I'm unsure how to wireup the dependencies correctly.

Comment: Do you have to use guice ? Did you look at Scala's cake pattern ? Here is a nice article that you may want to take a look: http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/

Comment: The core idea of Dependency Injection is to *ask* for dependencies instead of doing lookup or manual creation. Your service violates that. You need to read about DI more (for example google for Martin Fowler's article on DI) and then you'll understand how to solve your problem.

Comment: @PrzemekPokrywka I know I should have DBHelper.getDataSource and getDb as constructor parameters, but I'm confused since these are method calls and not sure how to wire those up with guice.

Comment: @Blankman Guice has concept called Provider useful for that. Hint: looks like the service needs only Dao. Inject only it. Db objects are likely needed in Dao only.